# yii2 joinwith multiple tables

Tags: yii2, join

i am using kartik gridview and i want to display the result page using joinwith multiple tables. below i used select statement to fetch the output same i need to display in index page(highlighted in bold) insted of select query

```
$query = EmpDetails::find()->joinWith(['employeeStatutoryDetail'])
            ->where(['NOT IN', 'emp_statutorydetails.gpa_no', ['']])
            ->orWhere(['IS NOT', 'emp_statutorydetails.gpa_no', NULL]);
```

And my query:

```
SELECT A.empcode,A.empname,
       B.designation,
       C.division_name,
       D.gpa_no,D.gpa_sum_insured,
       E.fellow_share
  FROM emp_details AS A JOIN designation 
                   AS B JOIN division 
                   AS C JOIN emp_statutorydetails 
                   AS D JOIN vg_gpa_hierarchy 
                   AS E JOIN vg_gpa_policy 
                   AS F ON F.policy_no=D.gpa_no 
  WHERE D.empid=A.id AND 
        A.designation_id=B.id AND 
        A.division_id=C.id AND 
        E.sum_insured=D.gpa_sum_insured
```

Comment: is your raw query generating correct results?

Answer (score 0):

To model EmpDetails add additional attributes designation,division_name,gpa_no, gpa_sum_insured and fellow_share. 
For searching and sorting suggest create extended model EmpDetailsSearch.